# How to know if a number is the square of a rational?

Tags: number-theory

I'm pretty new with Mathematica and I was looking for a way to know whether a number is a square of a rational. I thought of

```
Head[Sqrt[myNumber]] == Rational
```

where `myNumber` came from replacing some variables with rational and integer numbers in a polynomial equation.

Is there a better way to do it for large numbers, perhaps without computing the square root?

Comment: For starters, `Sqrt[myNumber] ∈ Rationals` returns a correct result for integers and your solution doesn't, so I guess it's an improvement. However, I don't know what results you want for machine precision numbers...
Sidenote: Use triple === when you want the result to be False when it is not True. == remains unevaluated for symbolic arguments

Comment: I'd like to complement Rojo's comment a little: `Head` is a programming construct which test "data types".  `Element[number, Rationals]` is a mathematical construct which tries to test if a number is mathematically a rational number.  It may be necessary to use `Simplify` with `Element` to ask Mathematica to spend a bit more time to try to figure out the answer.

Comment: First, thanks to both. I was using `Head` because checking the internal type seems to me the fastest way to do it. It should not work at all with machine precision number, I don't really need to use them. I'll do it with `Element`, many thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

The only trick I can see is a trivial one: if $x$ is the square of a rational, it is also a rational. That's because of the  $x = (a/b)^2 = a^2/b^2$.

So, I'd write a function testing the rationality, which returns either `True`, `False`, or `Null` (if rationality cannot be established):

```
isRational[x_] := If[Simplify[x ∈ Rationals], True, False, Null]
```

which works like this:

```
In[30]:= isRational /@ {1/3, π, EulerGamma}
Out[30]= {True, False, Null}
```

And then simply use it by first checking if the number itself is known to be rational:

```
isSqrRational[x_] := If[isRational[x], isRational[Sqrt[x]], False, isRational[Sqrt[x]]]
```

which gives:

```
In[33]:= isSqrRational /@ {1/3, 1/4, π, EulerGamma}
Out[33]= {False, True, False, Null}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to test if a number is a square of a rational, without taking square roots:

```
SetAttributes[squareQ, Listable];
squareQ[x_] := MatchQ[Head[x], Integer | Rational] && 
                      And @@ OddQ[DivisorSigma[0, Through[{Numerator, Denominator}[x]]]]
```

See e.g. [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=BFtOuh5xGOwC&pg=PA92) for a proof.

Comment: I can only assume that avoiding square roots is to reduce computational complexity. How well does DivisorSigma[0, n] scale with n?

Answer (score 3):

How do you know if a number $a$ is the square of a rational?

`Lemma: The rationals which are squares of rational numbers are themselves either squares of whole numbers or ratios of such squares.`

`Algorithm:`

So if you're given a rational number, say $a=\frac{n}{d}$  where $n$ and $d$ have no common divisors, then $a$ is the square of a rational if and only if $n$ and $d$ are also squares of whole numbers.

Suppose $a= 0.6428571428571428571$. First you convert it into fractions without common factors:

```
Rationalize[0.6428571428571428571]
9/14

n=Numerator[Rationalize[0.6428571428571428571]]
d=Denominator[Rationalize[0.6428571428571428571]]
```

Then you gotta check if all of the exponents of the prime factors of $n$ and $d$ are even.

Now  `FactorInteger` does the job here. It lists primes and its exponents:

```
FactorInteger[n]
{{3, 2}}
FactorInteger[d]
{{2, 1}, {7, 1}}
```

Now if the 2nd entries of both of these matrices are even then you're golden. For this you use `EvenQ`

```
EvenQ[#[[2]] & /@ FactorInteger[n]]
{True}
EvenQ[#[[2]] & /@ FactorInteger[d]]
{False, False}
```

If any `False` shows up then your answer is No.

`Proof of Lemma:`

Well, if $a$ is itself irrational then it cannot be the square of a rational by definition.

So now we need to know when a rational number $a$ is the square of rationals.

So lets suppose $a =\frac{n}{d}$ , a rational number where $n$ and $d$  are whole numbers that have no common divisors.

Now if $a=\frac{n}{d} = \frac{g^2}{h^2}$, where $g$ and $h$ are whole numbers with no common divisors.

then

$n*h^2 = d*g^2$ ---(1)

Let $\prod_k p^{a_k}_k$ be the prime factorization of $n$ then each $a_k$ must be even, since $p_k$ divides $d*g^2$ and since $p_k$ does not divide $d$, it must divide $g$. This implies that   $p_k$ shows up with an even exponent on the `rhs` of (1). Also, since $g$ and $h$ don't have any common factors, $p_k$ shows up on the `lhs` only under the factorization of $n$. Therefore $a_k$ is even. Since $p_k$ was arbitrarily chosen, the exponents of all prime divisors of $n$ are even. Therefore $n$ is a perfect square. By symmetry, the same argument demonstrates that $d$ is a perfect  square as well.

QED.